# does it mean i have only one usb2 port?

Tags: usb

I am planning to buy an external HDD.For this i am trying to find out what type of usb port i have.From control panel i found this following setup .It says in number 5->family usb2 enhanced host controller.But the previous ones saying only "USB HOST CONTROLLER"

I have 6 usb port and they all came at the same time.Does it mean i have only one usb2 port and others are not usb2?

[image]

Comment: How old is the PC?

Comment: Since it seems that the PC is running something newer than windows XP, I would assume that all your ports are usb2.

Comment: pc almost 6 years old.changed the motherboard two years ago .currently running windows 7

Comment: Intel’s UHCI implementation can handle 2 ports per root hub. All Intel USB 1.x controllers are UHCI. There’s OHCI as well, according to Linux sources it can handle 16 ports per root hub.

Comment: If you can tell us which motherboard you have, it would be easy to get the information from the manufacturer, and nobody would need to make any generalized statements.

Comment: @DanielB oops, you're absolutely right. My apologies. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all your USB ports are likely USB 2.0. The USB 2 controller's presence in the device manager output doesn't imply a separate port, that being the only one that can run USB 2. Rather, that controller sort of wraps around the existing USB 1 controllers' ports and lets them run USB 2 as well as USB 1.

The USB hardware in the ICH7 is a strange beast. It first comes up in USB 1 mode (because it can't assume that there are drivers that would know how to talk to it in USB 2 mode). Note that there are four USB 1 controllers, but actually eight USB ports' worth of pins on the IHC7, because each controller comes with a USB "root hub", with two ports, built in. So when it first powers on you have eight USB 1.1 ports.

But then, a USB 2-compatible driver shows up, finds the "USB2 Enhanced USB Controller", and enables it. It can "take over" any or all of the four pairs of USB ports in the IHC7. From then on, whichever pairs of USB ports it's taken over run as USB 2. (There is normally no reason for it not to take over all of them.) They can of course still talk to USB 1.x devices.

See the [Intel® I/O Controller Hub 7 (ICH7) Family Datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/datasheet/i-o-controller-hub-7-datasheet.pdf). Page 63 describes the pins on the chip (these are the outputs of the root hubs, so there are eight ports' worth total), page 200 describes the UHCI (USB 1) controllers, and the key stuff about the EHCI controller is on page 207:

> The ICH7 contains an Enhanced Host Controller Interface (EHCI) host controller which supports up to eight USB 2.0 high-speed root ports. USB 2.0 allows data transfers up to 480 Mb/s **using the same pins** as the eight USB full-speed/low-speed ports. The ICH7 contains port-routing logic that determines whether a USB port is controlled by one of the UHCI controllers or by the EHCI controller. USB 2.0 based Debug Port is also implemented in the ICH7.

(emphasis added)

So, the single EHCI controller can deal with all eight of the IHC7's "root hub" USB ports, corresponding to all four of the "USB Universal ..." devices. Note: Not all eight of these may be wired up on your motherboard, and one or two might be connected to USB devices that are *on* the motherboard - the latter is often the case in laptops.